# Почему содержимое head передаётся в body PHP?

Tags: php, шаблоны

Пытаюсь сделать шаблоны страниц. На одном сайте нашёл код, который только частично работает. После выполнения скрипта, на готовой странице в тэге `<head>` не пишется ничего, но пишется в `<body>`, хотя в шаблоне прописано нормально. Вероятно дело в функции `renderTemplate` или том, как формируется контент. Как это исправить?

Страница сборки:

```
<?php
function renderTemplate($template, $param = false) {
  ob_start();
  if ($param) {
    extract($param);
  }
  include($template);
}
$items_list = ['patch' => 'pa', 'id'=>'id', 'title'=>'ti', 'temp'=>'et'];
// Этот блок выводится первым, а после него всё содержимое тэга head и остаток страницы
$page_content = renderTemplate('main.php', ['items' => $items_list]);
$layout_content = renderTemplate('layout.php',
['content' => $page_content, 'title' => 'Dnevnik наблюдений за погодой']);

print($layout_content);
?>
```

Страница шаблона (layout.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?= $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="main-header">
      <h1 class="visually-hidden">Дневник погоды</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
      <main class="content"><?= $content; ?></main>
    </div>
    <footer class="main-footer">Дневник наблюдения за погодой.</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Контент (main.php):

```
<div class="content__main-col">
  <h2 class="visually-hidden">Последние записи</h2>
  <a class="button" href="">Добавить новую</a>
  <ul class="items-list">
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
      <?=renderTemplate('item.php', ['item' => $item]);?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

item.php

```
<li class="list-item">
  <div class="picture">
    <img src="uploads/preview_<?php echo $item['path']; ?>">
  </div>
  <h3 class="desc-title">
    <a href="/view?id=<?php echo $item['id'];?>"><?php echo "title ".$item['title'];?></a>
  </h3>
  <div class="desc-data">
    <span class="temp"><?php echo $item['temp'];?></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: это каша, а не код.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, знаю. Но какой нашёл, тот написал. Не подскажите тогда более хорошее решение для создания шаблонов без дополнительных библиотек?